# RTOS dependency on toolchain and target

Tags: operating-system, rtos, toolchain

Considering any RTOS source code there are couple of files that are specific to 1-Target 2-Compiler. There can be a minimal dependency of the word-size of target controller, interrupt calling the kernel tick function etc. Are there any other dependencies...?       Thanks in advance

Comment: There are usually more than a couple of files:)  An RTOS will need multiple target-dependent drivers, assuming it does some I/O :)  The kernel tick function is only one such driver and, indeed, is not an absolute necessity.

Comment: It is RTOS dependent.  Some RTOS are no more than scheduling kernels, others are complete OS with file-systems, I/O, networking etc.  As such this question is too broad for SO. Pick an RTOS, read its documentation.

Comment: So if we consider the RTOS dependency on the compiler (not the target), ex freeRTOS may have an IAR or GCC folder. What may be the purpose of that kind of a dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While working with Micrium and FreeRTOS, I found that since context switching is performed many times between tasks and ISR, it is a general practice to write the best optimized code for storing CPU registers onto task's stack while switching context. To get the best optimization, the CPU register handling is generally written in assembly language. And this is one reason for compiler (toolchain) dependency of RTOS.